# Difference between th:text and th:value in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I just recently started using Thymeleaf through one of my projects. I have seen few examples where `th:text=${example}` is being used in some places `th:value=${example}`.

I have gone through the Thymeleaf documentation but couldn't find anything explicitly citing the difference, nor did any question on SO.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `th:value` is modification of html attribute `value`. 
  For button, input and option elements, the value attribute specifies the initial value of the element
- `th:text` is used for tag body modification.

```css
div{background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px} // to highlight empty div
```

```html
<!--th code:               <div th:value="${value}"/></div> -->
<br/>Result th:value div:  <div value="sometext"/></div>
        
<!--th code:               <form><input th:value="${value}"/></form>-->
<br/>Result th:value form: <form><input value="sometext"></form> 

<!--th code:               <div th:text="${value}"></div> 
Same as:                   <div>[[${value}]]</div> -->
<br/>Result th:text div:   <div>sometext</div>
```

Here is docs of different [Thymeleaf attributes features](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

Lets see an example:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
```

if we want to use thymeleaf in value portion of this input tag, then we will use,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" th:value="${someValue}"> Male<br>
```

if we want to see the text **(here Male)** sent from the controller dynamically, then we use,

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" th:text="${someText}""> <br>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to know! So basically text is to display content from the controller and value is to fill a model, right?

Answer (score 0):

**th:name** => This would be the name of the value that you will be passing to another page (Exemplar scenario).

**th:value** => This would be the actual value that you would be passing. It could be obtained from a model or straight from the database explicitly.

```
<form th:action="@{confirm-pass-details.html}">
    <button type="submit" th:name="event-id" th:value="${event.get().getEventid()}">Buy Passes</button>
</form>
```

[image: Just an example]